# compare values in nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have problem with very simple 2-stage dictionary.
My dictionary has keys (numeric), second keys (numeric) and name company in values.
I need to check ONLY key no 1, because I know that only possibility that "FORD" name appears - is dictionary[i][1]
And as you can see - string is not equal in 100% with key. Key can contain "Ford" (but key has another part name in it: "Ford Motor"), so if "Ford" appears in each Dictionary[i][1] - assign this key to empty dictionary "MATCHINGITEMS" in order:

```
matchingitems[1] = "Ford"
matchingitems[2] = "Ford" etc
```

Could you help me?

```
Dictionary = { „1” : { „1” : "Ford Motor",
                   „2” : "Volkswagen Autos"
                      }
               "2" : { "1" : "Ducati",
                       "2" : "Yamaha"
                      } 
              "3" : { "1" : "Ford",
                      "2" : "SEAT"
                    }
               }
matchingitems = {}
i = 0
for value in Dictionary.items():
    for key in Dictionary.items[value]:
        i += 1
        if "Ford" in Dictionary[i][1]:
             matchingitems[i] = "Ford"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly this does what you need:

```
 Dictionary = { "1" : { "1" : "Ford Motor",
                   "2" : "Volkswagen Autos"
                      },
               "2" : { "1" : "Ducati",
                       "2" : "Yamaha"
                      },
              "3" : { "1" : "Ford",
                      "2" : "SEAT"
                    }
               }
matchingitems = {}

for key,value in Dictionary.items():
    if 'Ford' in value['1']:
        matchingitems[key] = value['1']

print(matchingitems)
```

Comment: Won't `i` be random as the dict is (presumably) not an ordered dict, and therefore the index from enumerate may change?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've changed the code accordingly. It also wasn't exactly what OP wanted.

Comment: Also, key may increment more than 1, I think you need `matchingitems.append(value['1'])`

Comment: Please reload my answer, I changed it in the meantime :)

Comment: :-) Im giving you +1 for persistance!